# How do I customize Twitter Bootstrap using Less? (Navbar height)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I've come across articles such as [this one](http://blog.nyaruka.com/customizing-twitter-bootstraps-nav-bar-color) discussing how to modify components of [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) using [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). However, I don't know what I should include in my files or how they should be constructed.

How would I use LESS to modify the height of the navbar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First download the less files from github and then look up where the height is set. A quick look at the files learned me that the height is first set in navbar.less on line 22:

```
min-height: @navbarHeight;
```

As you can see a variable is used to set the height. A closer look at that same file shows that the variable is used a couple of times to set various heights of items inside the navbar.  The easiest way would be to change the value of that variable. It should be in the variables.less file. Set it to whatever you want it to be, and recompile your bootstrap.less.

If you ever decide to update your bootsrap version, you should be able to keep your variables.less file, and just change the rest of them to the new version. That is of course only the case if they do not add any new variables.

Answer (score 0):

PeterVR explains how to update the less locally after downloading it and setting up less.  However, if you wish, you can customize your bootstrap distribution before you download it on the [Twitter Bootstrap Customize](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#variables) page if you did not want to deal with recompiling less templates etc.

In the long run it may be better to download the source files yourself and manage the overrides that you make to the bootstrap defaults.  Otherwise this might meet your needs for a quick and easy override of the default settings.